# Google analytics shows referral traffic coming from (script loaded) 3rd party iFrame

Tags: iframe, cookies, google-analytics, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

We are testing our own custom tracking solution. Our solution consists out of a script that loads an iframe (from our subdomain cookies.example.com) to which cookies are written and read from. The script is placed on the websites of our clients.

Now we are testing out this solution with a lot of people and some of them report that they see referral traffic in google analytics showing up coming from cookies.example.com.

I can't find the source of the problem (also because I can't reproduce the issue). Does anyone have a clue?

**UPDATE:**

I just talked to an Adwords support agent (they are the closest you can get to analytics support) who claimed it had to do with hierarchal nature of frames. I concluded that that would mean that all pages (on the internet) containing both GA tracking and a random third party iframe would have this issue. The support agent confirmed this. I find this hard to believe as I can't find any information on this and I would expect this to be a relative big issue for others as well.

**EDIT:**
Regarding dm-guy's questions:

The script is located in the body. Ga version is Analytics.js. Here is a simplified version of the code that loads the iframe:

```
my.Beacon.makeBeaconFrame = function(callback) {
    if (my.beacon) { return; }

    ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", my.beaconUrl + '/?' + my.beaconVersion);
    ifrm.style.width = 1+"px";
    ifrm.style.height = 1+"px";
    ifrm.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

    if (window.addEventListener){
        addEventListener("message",my.Beacon.listener, false)
    } else {
        attachEvent("onmessage", my.Beacon.listener)
    }

    ifrm.onload = function() {
        my.beacon = ifrm.contentWindow;
        callback();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your script located? (I assume it's a JS code?). In the head? or Body? Which GA version you use?
Generally Google Analytics takes the HTTP referrer, so I wonder why would the HTTP referrer change while using your cookie. If you can add a code or an example it would be helpful.